# Create feature classes with regular numbering using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, propertyname

I want to create 12 feature classes from a tuple, and I would like to have specific names that start form `well_0` and end with `well_11`.

```
in_FC = "E:/gis payannameh/TABU search/data/90spring_new.shp"
out_FC = r'E:\gis payannameh\Pychram_tabu\output.gdb'
well = ('10,24,38,41', '17,26,34,47', '5,7,18,25', '7,12,26,46', '2,12,23,36', '7,18,21,43', '2,13,16,39', '5,8,32,43', '1,9,17,44', '8,13,30,46', '2,14,34,37','3,15,12,9')
for i in range(len(well)):
     templayer = "templayer_{}".format(i)
     sql = """ {0} IN ({1})""".format("FID",well[i])
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_FC,"templayer",sql)
     arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(templayer,out_FC,"well_{}".format(i))
```

but when I use `ListFeatureClasses` for `i=2` it shows `well_10`, `[well_0,well_1,well_10,well_11,well_2,...well_9]`.I would Like to create each feature class'name with its index name(`i`) regularly something like `[well_0,well_1,well_2,...,well_11]`.

Comment: Use 01, 02 etc instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and `Select_analysis`:

```
import arcpy, os

in_FC = "E:/gis payannameh/TABU search/data/90spring_new.shp"
out_FC = r'E:\gis payannameh\Pychram_tabu\output.gdb'
well = ('10,24,38,41', '17,26,34,47', '5,7,18,25', '7,12,26,46', '2,12,23,36', '7,18,21,43', '2,13,16,39', '5,8,32,43', '1,9,17,44', '8,13,30,46', '2,14,34,37','3,15,12,9')

for e, w in enumerate(well):
     sql = """{0} IN{1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=in_FC, field=arcpy.Describe(in_FC).OIDFieldName), tuple([int(v) for v in w.split(','))]) #Split the string into a list, convert to tuple
     newname = 'well_{0}'.format(e)
     arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=in_FC, out_feature_class=os.path.join(out_FC, newname), where_clause=sql)
```

Comment: @BERA.Its Create `[u'well_0.shp', u'well_1.shp', u'well_10.shp', u'well_11.shp', u'well_2.shp', u'well_3.shp', u'well_4.shp', u'well_5.shp', u'well_6.shp', u'well_7.shp', u'well_8.shp', u'well_9.shp']`.and didn't  change

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: @BERA.I would like to when I use `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` in `out_FC` for `e=2` show me `well_2.shp` not `well_10.shp`I hope you understand.

Comment: Not really. You have duplicate FIDs in your well list, you know that right?

Comment: I checked I don't have duplicate FIDs in `well`.

Comment: Yes you do. `from collections import Counter
print(Counter(','.join(well).split(',')).most_common())`. You have 7 and 12 three times each

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130142/discussion-between-mohammad-hassan-moayyedian-and-bera).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your confusion. Unexpected result caused by the way text variables are sorted. This code:

```
List1,List2 =[],[]
for i in range (11):
    List1.append('W_%i' %i)
    List2.append('W_%s' %str(i).zfill(2))
List1.sort()
List2.sort()
for item in zip(List1,List2):
    print '%s%s%s' %(item[0].rjust(5),chr(9),item[1])
```

outputs:

```
  W_0   W_00
  W_1   W_01
 W_10   W_02
  W_2   W_03
  W_3   W_04
  W_4   W_05
  W_5   W_06
  W_6   W_07
  W_7   W_08
  W_8   W_09
  W_9   W_10
```

You need to add leading zero in string format, so, simply change last bit of your code from:

```
(templayer,out_FC,"well_{}".format(i)
```

to:

```
(templayer,out_FC,"well_%s" %str(i).zfill(2)
```